# How to update records in tables in Oracle APEX using javascript/html?

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, oracle-apex

Currently I have a page in Oracle APEX that all html based. The page actually consists for a map and a region with the coordinates of the location that the user clicks on the map.

I'm stuck at how do I update my tables in APEX using the values from my html page.

Thanks for any guidance or help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is simplest way:
Dynamic Action on button, Execute Javascript code

```
var oDBGet = new htmldb_Get(null, $v('pFlowId'), "APPLICATION_PROCESS=SAVE_COORDS", $v('pFlowStepId'));
oDBGet.add('P25_NAME', $v("P25_NAME"));
oDBGet.add('P25_XCOORD', $v("P25_XCOORD"));
oDBGet.add('P25_YCOORD', $v("P25_YCOORD"));

oDBGet.get();
```

Page Process, AJAX Callback:

```
insert into coordinates
(name, xcoord, ycoord)
values
(:P25_NAME, :P25_XCOORD, :P25_YCOORD);
```

Answer (score 5):

I made a quick mock-up: try it [here](http://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54687:25)

This is my page setup:
[image: page setup]

Dynamic Action on my button, Execute Javascript code (i used a button, could just as well bind this to any other element):

```
var oDBGet = new htmldb_Get(null, $v('pFlowId'), "APPLICATION_PROCESS=SAVE_COORDS", $v('pFlowStepId'));
oDBGet.addParam('x01', $v("P25_NAME"));
oDBGet.addParam('x02', $v("P25_XCOORD"));
oDBGet.addParam('x03', $v("P25_YCOORD"));

oDBGet.get();
```

the refresh is on the report region, to show it works.

htmldb_Get is a bit of an undocumented function in apex.

- parameter 1: session id -> unnecessary hence null
- parameter 2: application id (so you could use `&APP_ID.` for
  substitution string, but this is unusable in a .js file)
- parameter 3: the process to be executed. This can be an application
  or page process. Defined by parameter 4
- parameter 4: page id (again, `&APP_PAGE_ID.` is usable). If not
  provided the process is assumed to be an application level process
  (shared components->...)

`apex_application.g_x##`, 01 through 10 are 10 possible variables used for temporary storage. You pass them on like i showed: `x01`, `x02`, ... In the application process you can then reference them through `apex_application.g_x##`.

Page Process, AJAX Callback:

```
insert into coordinates
(name, xcoord, ycoord)
values
(apex_application.g_x01, apex_application.g_x02, apex_application.g_x03);
```

To customize this to your needs, you'll need to bind the event to the correct selectors, and provide the correct variables.

Answer (score 0):

Might it be possible that in APEX 4.1 the add method does not work?

Comment: In Apex 4.1 the new htmldb_Get call still works but 'addParam' or 'add' already does not, at least I could not make it to work. So I think other solution needs to be found for passing parameter to the Application process. Sadly I know very little of Javascript and zhe APEX JS API, so I am also looking for some help to solv this issue.

Comment: Why? Show your code and what error you receive? addParam and add works perfect in apex 4.1.